# Excel and JavaScript: Can functions use 3D references as parameters?

Tags: javascript, excel

For example, if calling JavaScript function fcn() from Excel, could JavaScript handle Sheet1:Sheet4!C3:G9 as an argument? VBA doesn't support them, but XLLs do, and since the NPV function accepts 3D references, there's a specific order iterator for 3D references somewhere inside Excel.

Comment: I don't know how to handle 3D refs from an XLL   - it is not documented anywhere, xlOper does not support it, but MoreFunc managed it somehow ... Neither VBA nor JavaScript has an official mechanism for handling 3D refs. The solution would be either explicit support (which I don't think exists) or  a means of getting the function signature from within the formula (but have to handle more than 1 call to the 3D func within a formula) and then exploding the 3D refs yourself- I suspect that is how the native 3D capable funcs do it. The new VSTACK func is 3D capable

Comment: Thanks. I figure I'll need to wait for VSTACK and HSTACK. FWIW, I've been using VBA udfs with 3 arguments for pseudo 3D references: 2 for opposite corners of the 3D block, and a dummy argument not used within the udf but to force the recalc engine to recognize the entire 3D block as a dependency, eg, foo(alpha!C3,omega:G9,COUNTA(alpha:omega!C3:G9). Klunky, but it works.

Comment: I like your COUNTA approach - that is clever.